# find a pattern for this ugly switch block (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```
switch (`(${wf}, ${hf})`) {
    case '(0, 0)': return 0;
    case '(1, 0)': return 1;
    case '(2, 0)': return 2;
    case '(0, 1)': return 3;
    case '(1, 1)': return 4;
    case '(2, 1)': return 5;
    case '(0, 2)': return 6;
    case '(1, 2)': return 7;
    case '(2, 2)': return 8;
}
```

is there a easy way of doing this?
I am trying to find a pattern but couldn't.

Comment: Maybe when flipping them the pattern becomes more obvious? It's just two [trits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could calculate the value.

```
(wf, hf) => 3 * hf + wf;
```

Comment: Pretty but completely unreadable or guessable what is going on

Comment: @mplungjan, i don't even know the meaning `wf` or `hf`. anyway. personally i would change the parameters.

Comment: thanks you so much it's working.....get outa here ugly switch-statement

Comment: hf - heightFactor, wf - widthFactor........... it's actually my vue project..... it's pretty complicated to explain

Answer (score 1):

Very short: Ternary (base 3):

```
console.log(parseInt(`${hf}${wf}`,3))
```

---

Other solution still readable as values

```js
const vals = ['00','10','20',
              '01','11','21',
              '02','12','22'];

const wf = 0, hf = 2
console.log(vals.indexOf(`${wf}${hf}`))
```

Comment: yep it works but it will become lengthy if more values are added

Comment: See my update: `parseInt(\`${hf}${wf}\`,3)`

Comment: is that base 3?